# RetroFit handle geneirc responses in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I currently have `login` and `register` endpoints that return similar JSON, the former returns the JWT token and the latter the user id, either way in my repository I have this code:

```
suspend fun login(user: User) = try {
    val response = api.login(user)
    LoginResult.Content(response.token)
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    LoginResult.Error(t)
}

suspend fun register(user: User) = try {
    val response = api.register(user)
    RegisterResult.Content(response.id!!)
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    RegisterResult.Error(t)
}
```

My `LoginResult` looks like this:

```
sealed class LoginResult {
    data class Content(val accessToken: String) : LoginResult()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : LoginResult()
}
```

and my `RegisterResult` looks very similar:

```
sealed class RegisterResult {
    data class Content(val id: Int) : RegisterResult()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : RegisterResult()
}
```

Clearly I have a lot of duplicate code between these two and considering that I'll have many more requests to handle it will only get worse. Besides this there are also the appropriate ViewStates to think about.

```
sealed class LoginViewState {
    object Loading : LoginViewState()
    data class Content(val accessToken: String) : LoginViewState()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : LoginViewState()
}
```

A similar one exists for register and they are being used in the Motors:

```
class LoginMotor : ViewModel() {
    private val _results = MutableLiveData<LoginViewState>()
    val results: LiveData<LoginViewState> = _results

    fun login(user: User) {
        _results.value = LoginViewState.Loading

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val result = AuthRepository.login(user)

            _results.value = when (result) {
                is LoginResult.Content -> { LoginViewState.Content(result.accessToken) }
                is LoginResult.Error -> LoginViewState.Error(result.throwable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and another such motor for registration. Now I'm trying to use a generic approach here and I can add generics to the `EndpointResult`, but how can I make the `ViewState` generic when I have to use a `Loading` state which is an object and cannot be generic since it's a singleton? This doesn't work:

```
sealed class DataViewState<T> {
    object Loading : LoginViewState() //error
    data class Content<T>(val data: T) : LoginViewState<T>()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : LoginViewState()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

```
sealed class DataViewState {
    object Loading: DataViewState()
    data class Content<T>(val data: T): DataViewState()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable): DataViewState()
}
```

```
sealed class GenericResult {
    data class Content<T>(val data: T) : GenericResult()
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : GenericResult()
}
```